# How to count TBB processing instructions?

Tags: profiling, intel, tbb, instructions

Intel TBB suggests users to adjust grain size to about 10,000 to 100,000 processing instructions for most efficient parallelism. However, there isn't a guideline as to what counts as a processing instruction. Do I count summations, equalization, multiplication, comparison, etc.; and, if I do, what are the weights of these operations? Are there any profiling tool that count processing instructions the way that TBB means?

Comment: On linux, `perf stat` counts CPU instructions.  The ocperf.py wrapper for it makes it easy to count uops and other stuff that HW perf counters can tell you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a very rough recommendation to give an idea what is the reasonable execution time of one piece of computation work. The idea is that the computation task should not be too small and there is no benefits from too large tasks. Usually, you do not need to worry about these rule if you use parallel algorithm with a default partitioner (`auto_partitioner`).

In some cases (e.g. when you need to use `simple_partitioner`) you can measure the serial time of the algorithm and multiple it to a frequency of your CPU. This value can give you an idea about the number "instruction"/"clock ticks" of the whole problem. So you can divide the problem into pieces of the recommended size.

As for the tools, I suppose there are many profiling tools that can calculate the execution time (or CPU instructions) of your application on a particular platform. (See [List of performance analysis tools](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_performance_analysis_tools)). In addition, you can try Intel VTune Amplifier that can estimate the overhead introduced by Intel TBB (the tool has a special support for TBB based applications) to understand if the application uses TBB efficiently.

Comment: I tried Valgrind Cachegrind and VTune Amplifier to get the number of processing instructions and none of those results resonated with my simple experiments such as 1 million summation, multiplication, etc. I believe you are right in the sense that processing instructions do not exactly map to elapsed wall-clock times. And, those suggestions by TBB are only ballparks to give a rough idea to start with. Still, I was trying to back up my experimental findings with some theoretical work, but it seems a non-trivial task.

Answer (score 3):

Kevin.  As Alex says the guideline is approximate, and there are other concerns involved.  For instance, if part of the computation accesses data under a lock, that is going to probably dominate your time.  If there are imbalances in the computation work per task, that will make tweaking the unit size much less important.

I didn't find the TBB documentation that talks about determining partition size, but there is a slide set [here](https://compas.cs.stonybrook.edu/~nhonarmand/courses/fa15/cse610/slides/02-basics.pdf) that talks about the "bathtub graph" (slide 7.)  It demonstrates the point that getting an exact work load per task is not necessary; there will be a range that will work well.

The TBB scheduler also will try to balance the work across all processors by stealing task partitions from other CPUs if it can, so one unbalanced workload doesn't completely incapacitate you.